# why setting as autocmd

Tags: vimrc

To display linenumbers, I can do:
`:set number`    in the edited file (that works)
or insert
`set number`     in the .vimrc (that works too).

To change the filetype, I can do:
`:set filetype=c`    in the edited file (that works)
but when I insert:
`set filetype=c`    in the .vimrc  **it does not work.**

I have to use `au[tocmd]`, inserting

```
au Bufread,BufNewFile *.mc set filetype=c
```

in the .vimrc.

My question is: Why do I have to use `autocmd` for filetype, and
cannot just put `set filetype=c` in the .vimrc?

With the `linenumbers` I do not have to use an `autocmd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `.vimrc` is global to all your buffers and the `filetype` is local to each buffer.

When the `.vimrc` file is read the buffer is not yet.

The `autocmd` is defined to automatically set the file type when the buffer will be read (`BufNewFile` or `BufRead` event).

For `:set number` it is a default option that is copied when the buffer is read or created to its local version (that you can change using `:setlocal number`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there seem to be indeed be different kinds of options, some of which you can default in the .vimrc file, some not. Or it is just such that, in the case of filetype, vim FIRSTLY looks at the .vimrc file, and THEN does an automatic type assessment, so that the value in the .vimrc file is in the end never considered.

Comment: The `filetype` is particular option that can't be defined globally as number it can only be defined for a particular buffer. If the answer answer your question don't forget to validate the question using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons it allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try explaining in a different way. Vim is an editor that knows how to execute Ex commands, including `:set`.

It has a startup sequence that includes executing commands from certain files (mostly before any buffers are loaded and windows are opened).

It also has a `filetype` option, which `:help 'filetype'` tells is local to the current buffer. Since there is no indication that it also has a global value, you cannot set it globally. This means that `:set filetype=…` always affects the current buffer.

In contrast, the `number` option is local to the window and is thus inherited when windows are split (including when the very first window is opened).

The stuff at `:help options`, especially, `:help local-options`, explains this all in more detail, though I think it omits the case of certain buffer-local options that are *not* backed by a global option.

---

So consider the sequence of events when you have `:set filetype=c` in your vimrc:

1. Vim starts up and executes the command, but there is no current buffer.
2. Vim opens the window showing the buffer of the file you edit.

It makes sense that the first command had no effect! Moreover, you (probably) don't want *every* file you open in Vim to have `filetype=c`; check the list of filetypes in `:edit $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin`, and that's not even all of them!

You are probably more interested in the `:filetype` command, which you can place in your vimrc as `:filetype plugin indent on`. This enables auto-filetype detection, plugins, and indent settings.

As you found, you can customize detection with autocommands. The typical way to do so is with `~/.vim/filetype.vim` and `~/.vim/ftdetect.vim` (`:help new-filetype`). Similarly, you can write your own ftplugins and indent scripts (I recommend `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/…` and similar).